# Have random saving error with python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to replace some links in SharePoint docs, so I download docs locally, edit them and upload them back.The problem is python-docx's save() method causes script crush at random point. It has OSError related to the path, but the path is ok, os.path.exists says it's exists, so there definitely no option like trying to open not existent path.

The code is big and complicated, it's hard to make minimal examle, but I can provide some logs, maybe it will helps

```
Search for links to replace in D:\...\<filename>.docx 
Starting searching for and replacing links in <filename>.docx... 
path 'D:\...\<filename>.docx' exists: True 
Replaced hyperlink link 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<id>/edit#gid=590117954' with 'https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<name>/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%...D&file=<file>' in paragraph #189. 
path 'D:\...\<filename>.docx' exists: True 
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\...\\<filename>.docx' 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "D:\...\sharepoint_links_replacer.py", line 156, in <module>
        raise e   File "D:\...\sharepoint_links_replacer.py", line 100, in <module>
        processed_links = update_file(matched_doc, in_doc_matched_links, site)   
File "D:\...\utils\sharepoint\sharepoint_mfa.py", line 487, in update_file
        replaced_links = update_doc(file_name, in_doc_links)   
File "D:\...\utils\editors.py", line 1160, in update_doc
        replaced_links = docx_replace(file_name, links_dicts)   
File "D:\...\utils\editors.py", line 818, in docx_replace
        doc.save(local_file_path)   
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\docx\document.py", line 154, in save
        self._part.save(path_or_stream)   
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\docx\parts\document.py", line 115, in save
        self.package.save(path_or_stream)   
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 174, in save
        PackageWriter.write(pkg_file, self.rels, self.parts)   
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\pkgwriter.py", line 32, in write
        phys_writer = PhysPkgWriter(pkg_file)   File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\phys_pkg.py", line 141, in
    __init__
        self._zipf = ZipFile(pkg_file, 'w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED)   
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 1249, in
    __init__
        self.fp = io.open(file, filemode) OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\...\\<filename>.docx'
```

**The main idea** is what I have 3 steps:

- get bytes file content from SharePoint using GraphAPI and write it to the local file with file.write() inside the context manager "with".
- parse the document to get some links
- match and replace links.

The crush happens on the 3rd step. I am replacing the link by link (custom function docx_replace) and save local version of the document immidiately after every replacing (just believe me, it's necessary). And at some point, on the random document, it fails with the same message.

**Tech**

Bayoo-docx v.2.19 (which is fork of python-docx with commets support, not sure which version of python-docx they inherit.

**PS**: [The minimal code example of the function](https://codeshare.io/eVOlB9)

Comment: Please include your code.  At least the relevant parts to it.

Comment: @ewokx, thanks, for repliy, Added the shortened version of my function.  The thing is it works well on the same document if it is called directly on that document. But I get this error if it is used in a cicle for a lot of documents. All the documents of course are deleted after the uploading to SharePoint, so it's not about "No more space left".